# Inherit pure virtual function implementation from different base class?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to inherit the implementation of an abstract function from another base class in multiple inheritance?

Here is a simple example, which doesn't compile without the commented code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    
    void bar() {
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
    }
};

class B {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "It works!\n";
    }
};

class C : public A, public B {
public:
    // void foo() override {
    //     B::foo();
    // }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Class A needs a function `foo()` for `bar()` to work, and so I want to say "the child of A must have a function `foo()`".

In terms of my real code, I have a few different classes for A which handle data storage and manipulation in my program, and a few different classes for B which handle how `foo()` is defined. I then want classes that combine each permutation of this functionality into a class as automatically as possible, i.e. without having to define the commented out code in each my new C classes.

Is this possible? Is there a different program design that would let me do this?

Comment: @MooingDuck How does `C` contain 2 `A` objects?

Comment: @MooingDuck `B` doesn't inherit from `A`.

Comment: Please provide example which matches your example more accurately. We can provide alternative solution if we understand your actual code. Your question has to much focus on how you thing this should be solved and to little on what actual problem is.

Comment: If `A` is a placeholder for different classes, what's the point of defining `foo` as virtual function in this class? You won't be able to use convert a completely unrelated type `A2` to a reference to `A`. One way of solving this issue would be to use a template, but in that case you could simply remove `foo` from `A`...

Comment: `classes that combine each permutation` this seams like work for templates, but as I complained earlier there is no enough details to be sure or how it should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [Virtual Inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance)

Create

```
class Base{
    public: 
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Derive both your classes from it:

```
class A : public virtual Base {
public:
    void bar() {
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
    }
};

class B : public virtual Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "It works!\n";
    }
};
```

Class C could be just empty:

```
class C : public A, public B {
};
```

And make the call:

```
int main() {
    C c;
    c.bar();
}
```

See the [DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/chxhnTf1Y)

Comment: Well, sort of; making this change overrides `A::foo` through **dominance**. But choosing virtual inheritance is a **design** decision, based on what the class hierarchy should look like. It should not be an **implementation** decision to make it easier to write some particular bit of code.

Comment: That's a fair comment @PeteBecker. I haven't really given much information about my program (because it would take a while to describe), but I think in my case it does make sense

Comment: Why do you add `foo` to `C` at all? Virtual inheritance would do it automatically.

Comment: If you just *remove* the `virtual void foo() = 0;` from `A` then you can remove the definition of `foo` in `C`. Then it's just `struct C : A, B { };`, just as the OP wants. But I think "use virtual inheritance" is the right design.

Comment: @Jarod42, I know, I just wanted to change the original code as little as possible. And somehow uncommented these lines while copying. Anyway, you are correct, this is the wrong approach. All the changes should be show. Updated.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I totally agree and initially I wanted to make same statement in my post, but later I changed my mind to keep things simple and answer to original question, namely "Is it possible..."

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, my bad, during copy I somehow uncommented the copied method and decided to leave what I get as an initial code. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a template for combining base class and implementation and implementation.

```
template<class Base, class Impl>
class CImpl : public Base, private Impl
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        Impl::foo();
    }
};

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    void bar() {
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
    }
};

class A2 {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    void bar() {
        foo();
    }
};

class B {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "It works!\n";
    }
};

class B2
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "this works too\n";
    }
};

// helper for class name output

template<class T>
constexpr char const* ClassName = "Unknown";
template<>
constexpr char const* ClassName<A> = "A";
template<>
constexpr char const* ClassName<A2> = "A2";
template<>
constexpr char const* ClassName<B> = "B";
template<>
constexpr char const* ClassName<B2> = "B2";

using C = CImpl<A, B>; // your original main would work with this type alias

// helper for testing different combinations of classes with the original logic of main
template<class Base, class Impl>
void Test()
{
    std::cout << "-----------------------\n"
        << "Base = " << ClassName<Base> << "; Impl = " << ClassName<Impl> << '\n';

    CImpl<Base, Impl> c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();
}

int main()
{
    Test<A, B>();
    Test<A, B2>();
    Test<A2, B>();
    Test<A2, B2>();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
-----------------------
Base = A; Impl = B
It works!
It works!
It works!
It works!
-----------------------
Base = A; Impl = B2
this works too
this works too
this works too
this works too
-----------------------
Base = A2; Impl = B
It works!
It works!
-----------------------
Base = A2; Impl = B2
this works too
this works too
```

---

Alternatively you could get rid of virtual function altogether by making the `A` types templates with a template parameter specifying the base class.

```
template<class Impl>
class A : public Impl
{
public:

    static constexpr char const* AName = "A";

    void bar() {
        Impl::foo();
        Impl::foo();
        Impl::foo();
    }
};

template<class Impl>
class A2 : public Impl {
public:
    static constexpr char const* AName = "A2";

    void bar() {
        Impl::foo();
    }
};

class B {
public:
    static constexpr char const* BName = "B";

    void foo() {
        std::cout << "It works!\n";
    }
};

class B2
{
public:
    static constexpr char const* BName = "B2";

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "this works too\n";
    }
};

// helper for testing different combinations of classes with the original logic of main
template<template<class> class Base, class Impl>
void Test()
{
    using C = Base<Impl>;

    std::cout << "-----------------------\n"
        << C::AName << "<" << C::BName << ">\n";

    C c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();
}

// the main function is the same as in the above code snippet
```

Output

```
-----------------------
A<B>
It works!
It works!
It works!
It works!
-----------------------
A<B2>
this works too
this works too
this works too
this works too
-----------------------
A2<B>
It works!
It works!
-----------------------
A2<B2>
this works too
this works too
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of the answer by @DamirTenishev, simply removing the pure virtual function from `A` and then removing the function from `C`, I think achieves the solution I'm looking for.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    
};

class A : public virtual Base {
public:
    void bar() {
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
    }
};

class B : public virtual Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "It works!\n";
    }
};

class C : public A, public B {};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

@fabian thanks for your template solution, that is quite clean, however I think in my particular case virtual inheritance does make a lot of sense. I think i will try out both solutions and see which makes the most sense in terms of design.

Without virtual inheritance this doesn't work.